# How to fill in nested lists?

Tags: r, arrays, list, matrix

Let´s suppose that my data has the following structure:

```
Phi_monthly<-array(matrix(1:3), c(10, 10, 2))
Phi_weekly<-array(matrix(1:3), c(10, 10, 2))
Phi_daily<-array(matrix(1:3), c(10, 10, 2))
```

I want to create a nested list using this information. I want to repeat the matrices in one list, but I want to repeat this process `n` times, were `n` is the `dim(Phi_monthly)[3]`. My problem is that I do not how can repeat this process.

Let me explain better. For example, when `dim(Phi_monthly)[3]` is 1, the code will be the following:

```
PHI<-lapply(rapply(
      list(lapply(seq_len(1), function(X) Phi_daily[,,1]),
           lapply(seq_len(6), function(X) Phi_weekly[,,1]),
           lapply(seq_len(23), function(X) Phi_monthly[,,1])
      ),
      enquote, how="unlist"), eval)
```

If `dim(Phi_monthly)[3]` is 2, the code will be:

```
PHI<-lapply(rapply(
      list(lapply(seq_len(1), function(X) Phi_daily[,,2]),
           lapply(seq_len(6), function(X) Phi_weekly[,,2]),
           lapply(seq_len(23), function(X) Phi_monthly[,,2])
      ),
      enquote, how="unlist"), eval)
```

I thought that I would like to create only one list(PHI) with 2 (dim(Phi_monthly)[3]) nested lists which contains 30 matrices(the result of my code)

My first idea was to use a `for`, but I am falling. If someone can help me or give me a clue I would be grateful.

Comment: Where does 1, 6, 23 come from?

Comment: @jay.sf 1, 6 and 23 is the number of times that I want to repeat my matrices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
all_lst <- lapply(1:dim(Phi_monthly)[3], 
       function(i){
         list(rep(list(Phi_daily[,,i]), 1),
              rep(list(Phi_weekly[,,i]), 6),
              rep(list(Phi_monthly[,,i]), 23)) %>% 
           unlist(recursive=FALSE)
         })
lengths(all_lst)
length(all_lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Map` to avoid repeated code.

```
l3 <- lapply(1:dim(Phi_monthly)[3], function(i)
  unlist(Map(replicate, c(1, 6, 23), 
             list(Phi_daily[,,i], Phi_weekly[,,i], Phi_monthly[,,i]), 
             simplify=F), recursive=FALSE))

lengths(l3)
# [1] 30 30
length(l3)
# [1] 2

identical(all_lst, l3)
# [1] TRUE
```